# Log4Net Exception to Appender?

Tags: c#, logging, log4net

Is it possible to log log4Net exceptions to a (or all) valid appenders? For example, I might have

```
<appender name="ConsoleAppender" type="log4net.Appender.ColoredConsoleAppender">
   <!-- ... --->
</appender>

<appender name="FileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
  <!-- ... -->
</appender>

<!-- Event Log Appender for errors-->
<appender name="EventLogAppender" type="log4net.Appender.EventLogAppender" >
   <!-- ... -->
</appender>

<root>
  <level value="DEBUG" />
  <appender-ref ref="ConsoleAppender" />
  <appender-ref ref="FileAppender" />
  <appender-ref ref="EventLogAppender" />
</root>
```

Say the `FileAppender` fails, the [default behavior of Log4Net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/faq.html#reliability) is to "output a single message to System.Console.Error and System.Diagnostics.Trace indicating that logging can not be performed."  Is there a way to configure or extend Log4Net so that it instead (or also) writes this error message to the valid appenders?

Comment: Not sure how that would work. You throw an exception during logging and you want to log it? Sounds like a recipe for stack overflow (TM)

Comment: @SteveTownsend During appender configuration actually, but you're right, you get into some gnarly edge cases.